# Generating refactored methods in snake case form thorugh QT creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

QT creator is an very versatile IDE. One of their nice features is the possibility for generating getter and setter methods. In order to do that, I click the right mouse button, I select `Refactor` and then it offers me the option for generating them.

However, it always generate them in camel case style. However, I tend to prefer snake case.

So my question is: is there any way for telling to QT creator that the refactored methods should be generated in snake case form?

Answer (score 1):

No, I think not. Please consider to request that feature at https://bugreports.qt-project.org/ .